# Как убрать тормоза, при быстром изменении TextView, во время прокрутки Slider

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `Slider` (вот [эта](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Slider) библиотека). Возможный прогресс от 10 до 30. Когда отметка изменяется на один пункт, `TextView` получает размер от текущего прогресса (к примеру, прогресс 17 = размер текста `17sp`). За изменение текста отвечает слушатель для `Slider`:

```
    ((Slider) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_select_textSize_slider_1)).setOnPositionChangeListener(new Slider.OnPositionChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPositionChanged(Slider slider, boolean b, float v, float v1, int i, int i1) {
                //i — позиция начала движения, i1 — позиция завершения движения

                //Если движение происходило в пределах одной единицы (изменилась
                //одна сотая, но слушатель сработал), значит return
                if (lastValue_1 == i && lastValue_2 == i1) {
                    return;
                }

                exampleText.setTextSize(i1*destin);

                lastValue_1 = i;
                lastValue_2 = i1;
            }

        });
```

Вот фото, как это выглядит на экране:

[image]

Вот вся активность — http://pastebin.com/D3U63vw8

---

Проблема в том, что, если быстро двигать слайдер, весь UI начинает тормозить. Как можно это исправить?

---

Вывел лог:

```
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "v = " + v + " v1 = " + v1);
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "i = " + i + " i1 = " + i1);
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "------------------------");

12-31 19:31:22.788  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.35604838 v1 = 0.36355317
12-31 19:31:22.788  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 17 i1 = 17
12-31 19:31:22.788  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.805  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.36355317 v1 = 0.3742385
12-31 19:31:22.805  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 17 i1 = 17
12-31 19:31:22.805  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.822  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.3742385 v1 = 0.38225
12-31 19:31:22.822  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 17 i1 = 18
12-31 19:31:22.822  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.863  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.38225 v1 = 0.39847514
12-31 19:31:22.863  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 18 i1 = 18
12-31 19:31:22.863  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.887  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.39847514 v1 = 0.40709662
12-31 19:31:22.887  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 18 i1 = 18
12-31 19:31:22.887  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.896  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.40709662 v1 = 0.41502383
12-31 19:31:22.896  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 18 i1 = 18
12-31 19:31:22.896  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.908  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.41502383 v1 = 0.423487
12-31 19:31:22.908  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 18 i1 = 18
12-31 19:31:22.908  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.924  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.423487 v1 = 0.4333088
12-31 19:31:22.925  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 18 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:22.925  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.958  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.4333088 v1 = 0.44628847
12-31 19:31:22.958  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:22.958  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.975  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.44628847 v1 = 0.45228577
12-31 19:31:22.975  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:22.976  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:22.993  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.45228577 v1 = 0.45597863
12-31 19:31:22.993  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:22.993  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.010  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.45597863 v1 = 0.45965818
12-31 19:31:23.010  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.010  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.027  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.45965818 v1 = 0.46323246
12-31 19:31:23.027  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.027  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.044  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.46323246 v1 = 0.46446446
12-31 19:31:23.044  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.044  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.062  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.46446446 v1 = 0.46816048
12-31 19:31:23.062  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.062  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.078  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.46816048 v1 = 0.4692405
12-31 19:31:23.078  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.078  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.095  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.4692405 v1 = 0.46939248
12-31 19:31:23.095  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.095  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.112  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.46939248 v1 = 0.4718565
12-31 19:31:23.112  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.112  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.146  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.4718565 v1 = 0.47374392
12-31 19:31:23.147  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.147  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.164  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.47374392 v1 = 0.47432047
12-31 19:31:23.164  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 19
12-31 19:31:23.165  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.334  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.47432047 v1 = 0.4836199
12-31 19:31:23.334  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 19 i1 = 20
12-31 19:31:23.334  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
12-31 19:31:23.366  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: v = 0.4836199 v1 = 0.48731795
12-31 19:31:23.366  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: i = 20 i1 = 20
12-31 19:31:23.366  30192-30192/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MainActivity: ------------------------
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, в условие вы никогда не попадёте, т.к. аргументы-то, поди, меняются при каждом вызове?.. Приводить код ссылкой - моветон. Сайт сей иногда заблокирован и ссылка может протухнуть. Отчего тормоза - неизвестно. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/kuchanov/tproger/fragment/FragmentDialogTextAppearance.java) на мою реализацию подобного - ничего не тормозит.

Comment: И как вы гарантируете, что после попыток разобраться в вашей проблемы вы не удалите вопрос лишив возможности ответить?.. =(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот только ради Вас и не удалю! :D

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у Вас все сложнее. Сейчас освобожусь и буду разбираться в Вашем коде. А пока меня нет, может и дадут ответ. А лаги из-за слишком частого изменения `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по либе старые значения приходят вместе с новыми, засим вам не нужны отдельные переменные для их хранения.

А проверка ваша, вроде, вообще не должна никогда `true` выдавать. Попробуйте сравнивать старые и новые значения так:

```
slider.setOnPositionChangeListener(new Slider.OnPositionChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPositionChanged(Slider view, boolean fromUser, float oldPos, float newPos, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if((oldPos - newPos) < 1)) { //изменение position меньше 1 }
        if((oldValue- newValue) < 1)) { //изменение value меньше 1 }
    }
});
```

P.S. вот как выглядит SeekBar на 4.1.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по логам (я не нашел документацию, пришлось так выяснять что там и где), переменные, которые Вы назвали `oldPos` и `newPos` не принимают значения более 1.0. Мне кажется, что это не то, что Вы подумали...

Comment: Пойду еще раз поиграюсь с логами, может понятнее станет.

Comment: @bukashka101 ну значит вам valie нужно

Comment: Вот черт! Второй раз за два дня Android Studio выдает ошибку при запуске и стирает мой фрагмент! Пойду снова переписывать.

Comment: Юрий, я добавил лог. Из него видно, что первые две переменные — это не прошлые позиции, а мое условие иногда срабатывает. :(

Comment: @bukashka101, судя по логам вам надо проверять только равенство `i` и `i1`. Они редко меняются и если равны тогда `return` делать.

Comment: Может проскочить случай, когда прогресс изменился, но они равны. Нужно делать, когда они два раза подряд равны.

Comment: Я посмотрел Ваш класс, который Вы скинули. Мой делает почти то же, мой код даже короче... Только у Вас он не тормозит, а у меня тормозит! Но почему :(.

Comment: Ладно, пусть притормаживает. Я оставил только `setText`, но оно все равно тормозит. Сейчас будет веселуха с плотностью таблицы! :D Я там вообще по 8 `TextView` за раз меняю. Ну... Их отступы.

Comment: Напишите просто, что ничего нельзя сделать.

Comment: @bukashka101, тормозить может из-за девайса и из-за кол-ва одновременно изменяемых элементов... Попробуйте по ссылке моей apk скачать и поменять размер текста. Если будет тормозить также - значит проблема не в коде, а в девайсе)

Comment: Юрий, ARMx64, 4x1Ггц, 1Гб ОЗУ! Издеваетесь?) Сейчас попробую скачать, посмотрим.

Comment: Неа, у Вас не тормозит.

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, попробуйте тогда как у меня Seekbar заюзать.

Comment: Юрий, `SeekBar` не так отображается на 4.2, как на 5.1...

Comment: @bukashka101, у меня везде как надо выглядит. Смотрите скин в ответе. У вас библиотека поддержки подключена? И тема в стилях от AppCompat наследуется?..

Comment: Юрий, не наследуется, потому что тема не `AppCompat`, а `Holo.Light.FullScreen.NoAction`, вроде

Comment: @bukashka101, нет ни одной причины использовать эту тему. А использовать `AppCompat` причин - тьма. Из-за `Holo.Light` у вас и проблемы с разным видом сикБара.

Comment: Юрий, пока что тормозну с написанием программы, друг (с ником satnov), обещал помочь с этой проблемой (да и вообще просмотреть мой код, скачать что не так, грубо говоря — наставить на путь истинный). Возможно, перепишусь под `AppCompat`, потому что нужно делать настройку с входом\выходом из фулскрина.